# What is the most performant way to rewrite a correlated subquery in the SELECT clause?

Tags: sql, database-performance, netezza, correlated-subquery

I am trying to count whether a user has visited a site in three time ranges:

- last 30 days
- between 31 and 60 days
- between 61 and 90 days

**I am using Netezza, which does NOT support correlated subqueries in the SELECT clause. See Rextester for successful query that must be re-written to NOT use a correlated subquery: http://rextester.com/JGR62033**

**Sample Data:**

```
| user_id | last_visit | num_days_since_2017117 |
|---------|------------|------------------------|
| 1234    | 2017-11-02 | 15.6                   |
| 1234    | 2017-09-30 | 48.6                   |
| 1234    | 2017-09-03 | 75.0                   |
| 1234    | 2017-08-21 | 88.0                   |
| 9876    | 2017-10-03 | 45.0                   |
| 9876    | 2017-07-20 | 120.0                  |
| 5545    | 2017-09-15 | 63.0                   |
```

**Desired Output:**

```
| user_id | last_30 | btwn_31_60 | btwn_61_90 |
|---------|---------|------------|------------|
| 1234    | 1       | 1          | 1          |
| 5545    | 0       | 0          | 1          |
| 9876    | 0       | 1          | 0          |
```

Comment: You don't need a correlated subquery here if the DBMS supports CASE or something similar.

Comment: Why the downvote? @a_horse_with_no_name? If there is additional clarity I can provide in the question then please comment. I feel I was clear and provided enough information to answer the question, no?

Comment: I didn't downvote. I commented.

Comment: @KenWhite can you clarify with an example of what this would look like using the sample data?

Comment: I don't know exactly what that DBMS supports, but you can use something like `SELECT user_id, SUM(CASE WHEN num_days <= 30 then 1 else 0 end) as last_30, SUM(CASE WHEN numdays > 30 AND numdays <=60 then 1 else 0 end) as btwn_31_60,`, etc. with a GROUP BY on user_id.

Comment: Thanks, the DBMS supports CASE statements. If you want to add this as an answer I will test it out and accept so future users can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way with conditional aggregation, [Rextester](http://rextester.com/VDNP65890):

```
select 
    user_id
    ,MAX(case when '2017-11-17'-visit_date <=30
          then 1
          else 0
     end) as last_30
    ,MAX(case when '2017-11-17'-visit_date >=31
               and '2017-11-17'-visit_date <=60
          then 1
          else 0
     end) as between_31_60
    ,MAX(case when '2017-11-17'-visit_date >=61
              and '2017-11-17'-visit_date <=90
          then 1
          else 0
     end) as between_61_90
from 
    visits
group by user_id
order by user_id
```

Comment: Since the context of this question is ‘most performant’ it is important to note that a correlated subquery as the one suggested in the original ‘rextester’ example is potentially MUCH slower than this case-based solution. Any ‘selfjoin’ can end up with the base table being scanned multiple times, and the chance of the query-plan being thrown off completely by the case construct/single table scan is extremely low :)

Comment: @Lars, I must have misunderstood the efficiency of correlated subqueries, and when to use them. Is this a true statement: conditionally checking the existence of criteria in a single table is best performed with a CASE statement, but conditionally checking the existence of criteria in a separate table is best performed with a correlated subquery?

Comment: @psrpsrpsr 1.) Checking for *existence* is usually quick and preferred over other subqueries 2.) Subqueries of any kind in a select add a risk of scanning the subquery table on a row-by-row basis  3.) `JOIN`s are usually preferred over select subqueries because you avoid #2 4.) The query optimizer may be smart enough to create the same plan whether you use a subquery or a `JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the specific DBMS you're using, but if it supports `CASE` or an equivalent you don't need a correlated sub-query; you can do it with a combination of `SUM()` and `CASE`.

Untested in your DBMS, of course, but it should give you a starting point:

```
SELECT 
  user_id, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN num_days <= 30 then 1 else 0 end) as last_30, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN num_days > 30 AND numdays < 61 then 1 else 0 end) as btwn_31_60,
  SUM(CASE WHEN num_days >= 61 then 1 else 0 end) as btwn_61_90
FROM 
  YourTableName  -- You didn't provide a tablename
GROUP BY 
  user_id
```

Since your values are floating point and not integer, you may need to adjust the values used for the day ranges to work with your specific requirements.

Comment: FYI, the table name and sample data are found in the Rextester link in the question. I was able to get the desired output by wrapping the SUM(CASE) in another CASE, like: CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN num_days <=30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

Comment: @psrpsrpsr: I saw the sample data, but not the table name (unless it's in the external link you provided, which my corporate proxy won't let me access - one more reason not to use external sites in your post). You shouldn't need the outer CASE (the one you added); I tested in SQL Server first, and it worked fine without it, although my test data used date values and DateDiff() rather than your data, because that's what I had available at the time.